tcpdump: How to show only Push-flag packets?
How can I filter tcpdump output (normal screen, not -w) to only see lines with flag [P]?
Running tcpdump 4.99 on Debian 12

tcpdump -i <INTERFACE> "tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-push) != 0"

